# `ui-grid` does not show all data until scrolled

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-grid

I have a `ui-grid` in a popup window with `ui-grid-auto-resize` and it binds to 30 rows. In initial loading with a grid default height of `300px` it shows 14 rows, and when I scroll to the last row it seem that it is loading the remain data on scrolling.

I have a post action on the controller and when I bind the data on it, the grid data is equal to `null` if I only scroll the grid and the first 15 rows if I do not scroll the grid.

When I watch the `formcollection` of form form read the last 15 rows of data when grid scrolling with index begin with 15.

When I set the height of grid to the amount of rows using javascript, it works fine, and grid data binds to control action correctly, but I need to scroll inside the grid because it's inside a popup window and the height of the grid exceeds the window size.